# Text not visible because of page break

Tags: formatting, positioning, parbox

I'm trying to force a page break since the text is not visible, but I can't. I still don't understand why the text is not visible, since the space is there... I'm very new to the LaTeX world, so I used a template[image].

The code:

```tex
%============================================================================%
%
%   DOCUMENT DEFINITION
%
%============================================================================%

%we use article class because we want to fully customize the page and dont use a cv template
\documentclass[10pt,A4]{article}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ENCODING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%we use utf8 since we want to build from any machine
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGIC
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% provides \isempty test
\usepackage{xifthen}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% some tex-live fonts - choose your own

%\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
%\usepackage[default]{comfortaa}
%\usepackage{cmbright}
%\usepackage[default]{raleway}
%\usepackage{fetamont}
%\usepackage[default]{gillius}
%\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[thin]{roboto} 

% set font default
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% more font size definitions
\usepackage{moresize}       


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE LAYOUT  DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%debug page outer frames
%\usepackage{showframe}         


%define page styles using geometry
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}      

% for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
\geometry{top=.5cm, bottom=-.6cm, left=-0.1cm, right=0cm}   

%use customized header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\pagestyle{fancy}

%less space between header and content
\setlength{\headheight}{-5pt}       


%customize entries left, center and right
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}

\newcommand{\padding}{1cm}
\newcommand{\innerwidth}{\linewidth-\padding-\padding}

%indentation is zero
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE /ARRAY DEFINITIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

%for layouting tables
\usepackage{multicol}           
\usepackage{multirow}

%extended aligning of tabular cells
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GRAPHICS DEFINITIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

%for header image
\usepackage{graphicx}

%for floating figures
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
%\floatstyle{boxed} 
%\restylefloat{figure}

%for drawing graphics       
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, backgrounds,mindmap, trees}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Color DEFINITIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{color}

%accent color
\definecolor{sectcol}{RGB}{3,101,140}

%dark background color 
\definecolor{bgcol}{RGB}{2,62,115}

%light background / accent color 
\definecolor{softcol}{RGB}{3,101,140}

% light bg 
\definecolor{light}{RGB}{235, 231, 231}

%============================================================================%
%
%
%   DEFINITIONS
%
%
%============================================================================%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% remove top header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

%remove botttom header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}      

%remove pagenum
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}   

%remove section num     
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}            

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARROW GRAPHICS in Tikz
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% a six pointed arrow poiting to the left
\newcommand{\tzlarrow}{(0,0) -- (0.2,0) -- (0.3,0.2) -- (0.2,0.4) -- (0,0.4) -- (0.1,0.2) -- cycle;}    

% include the left arrow into a tikz picture
% param1: fill color
%
\newcommand{\larrow}[1]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.58]
     \filldraw[fill=#1!100,draw=#1!100!black]  \tzlarrow
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

% a six pointed arrow poiting to the right
\newcommand{\tzrarrow}{ (0,0.2) -- (0.1,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.2,0.2) -- (0.3,0.4) -- (0.1,0.4) -- cycle;}

% include the right arrow into a tikz picture
% param1: fill color
%
\newcommand{\rarrow}[1]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
     \filldraw[fill=#1!100,draw=#1!100!black]  \tzrarrow
 \end{tikzpicture}
}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   custom sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% create a coloured box with arrow and title as cv section headline
% param 1: section title
%
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]
{
\colorbox{sectcol}{\mystrut \makebox[1\linewidth][l]{
\larrow{bgcol} \hspace{-8pt} \larrow{bgcol} \hspace{-8pt} \larrow{bgcol} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}\hspace{4pt}
}}\\
}

%create a coloured arrow with title as cv meta section section
% param 1: meta section title
%
\newcommand{\metasection}[2]
{
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2cm} p{11cm}}
\larrow{bgcol}  \normalsize{\textcolor{sectcol}{#1}}&#2\\[8pt]
\end{tabular*}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    CV EVENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% creates a stretched box as cv entry headline followed by two paragraphs about 
% the work you did
% param 1:  event time i.e. 2014 or 2011-2014 etc. 
% param 2:  event name (what did you do?) 
% param 3:  institution (where did you work / study) - took out
% param 4:  what was your position - took out
% param 5:  some words about your contributions - took out
%
\newcommand{\cvevent}[2]
{
\vspace{8pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.6\linewidth}{ p{12cm} x{3cm}}
\textbf{#2} &\textcolor{bgcol}{#1}\\[4pt]
    \end{tabular*}
\vspace{-12pt}
\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}
\vspace{6pt}
\vspace{-4pt}
}

% creates a stretched box as 
\newcommand{\cveventmeta}[2]
{
    \mbox{\mystrut \hspace{87pt}\textit{#1}}\\
    #2
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CUSTOM STRUT FOR EMPTY BOXES
%----------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CUSTOM LOREM IPSUM
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\lorem}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.}



%============================================================================%
%
%
%
%   DOCUMENT CONTENT
%
%
%
%============================================================================%

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{CAPAS/CAPA.png}

\includegraphics{CAPAS/ENSINO DE QUÍMICA.png}

%use our custom fancy header definitions
\pagestyle{fancy}   

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% HEADLINE / BASIC INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{bgcol}{bgcol}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.085\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
    \vspace{14pt}
    \textcolor{light}{\small{(UnB) $\cdot$  (IQ)  $\cdot$  PET $\cdot$ petunb}}\\
    \HUGE{\textcolor{white}{\textsc{Eduardo}} } \textcolor{sectcol}{\rule[-1mm]{1mm}{0.9cm}} \HUGE{\textcolor{white}{\textsc{EQ}} }
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}\\[-4pt]
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% SUMMARY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{sectcol}{sectcol}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.03\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{-3pt}
\begin{center}
\parbox[b]{0.75\linewidth}{
    \begin{center}
    \large
    \larrow{bgcol}\larrow{bgcol} \textcolor{white}{Conhecendo os professores!} \rarrow{bgcol}\rarrow{bgcol}
    \end{center}
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}\\[-4pt]
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% META
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{4pt}
\begin{center}
\parbox[c]{\innerwidth}{
    \includegraphics[trim= 320 130 460 210,clip,width=0.2\linewidth]{myfoto.jpg}
    \hspace{8pt}
    \parbox[b]{5cm}{
    \metasection{Vínculo:}{Professor Adjunto}
    \metasection{Título:}{Doutor} 
    \metasection{E-mail:}{ou}
    }
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}\\[-8pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% BARRA AZUL DE SEPARAÇÃO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{sectcol}{sectcol}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.02\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{-3pt}
\parbox[b]{0.65\linewidth}{}
\end{minipage}}\\[-8pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% LINHAS DE PESQUISA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{light}{light}{
\begin{minipage}[H][0.25\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{2pt}
\hspace{24pt}
\parbox[c]{0.75\linewidth}{


\cvevent{Atual}{Formação de Professores.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Jogos e Avaliação da Aprendizagem no Ensino.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Vídeos Digitais Amadores no Ensino.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Experimentação no Ensino.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Novas Tecnologias e Lúdico no Ensino.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Lúdico no Ensino.}

}
\hspace{18pt}
\textcolor{sectcol}{\rule[-3.2cm]{2pt}{6.5cm}}
\hspace{12pt}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\LARGE \textsc{Linhas de Pesquisa}}
\end{minipage}}\\[-10pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% BARRA AZUL DE SEPARAÇÃO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{sectcol}{sectcol}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.02\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{-5pt}
\parbox[b]{0.65\linewidth}{}
\end{minipage}}\\[-4pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÁREA DE ATUAÇÃO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.25\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{1pt}
\hspace{26pt}
\parbox[c]{0.75\linewidth}{
%\cvsection{Education}

\cvevent{Atual}{Exatas.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Educação.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Ensino.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Jogos e Atividades Lúdicas Em Ensino de Ciências.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Ensino-Aprendizagem.}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Atual}{Avaliação da Aprendizagem.}
}
\hspace{18pt}
\textcolor{sectcol}{\rule[-3.2cm]{2pt}{7cm}}
\hspace{12pt}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\LARGE \textsc{Áreas de Atuação}}
\end{minipage}}\\[-4pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% BARRA AZUL DE SEPARAÇÃO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{sectcol}{sectcol}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.02\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{-7cm}
\parbox[b]{0.65\linewidth}{}
\end{minipage}}\\[-4cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PROJETOS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{light}{light}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.36\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{-4cm}
\hspace{26pt}
\parbox[c]{0.75\linewidth}{
%
\cvevent{2016 - now}{Fullstack Javascript Engineer}{University of Bremen}{Invent a realtime classroom management using Meteor and React}{Design software architecture and leading development}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{2014 - 2016}{IT Consultant for IBM XPages and Notes Domino}{We4IT GmbH Bremen}{Realize projects in XPages and We4IT Aveedo, monitor project status, conduct reports}{Integrated Camunda BPMN engine and BPMN.IO modeler in We4IT Aveedo}


%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{2012 - 2014}{Scientific Employee / Software Development}{University of Bremen}{Invented a flexible assessment framework, targeting industrial trainees}{Supervised software development lifecycle, Recruited team members}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{Nov. 2011}{Project Management Simulation Training}{Getoq Consulting}{Performed a two-day project simulation from management perspective}{Topics included customer contracts, change management, controlling, operational tasks}

%\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}

%
\cvevent{2010 - 2011}{Student Assistant / Programmer}{otulea.uni-bremen.de}{Realized an online diagnosis platform for workforce literacy development (Flex)}{Modeled software design, implemented various prototypes, conducted usability tests}

}
\hspace{18pt}
\textcolor{sectcol}{\rule[-3.2cm]{2pt}{7cm}}
\hspace{12pt}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\LARGE \textsc{Projetos}}
\end{minipage}}\\[-4pt]

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% FOOTER
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fcolorbox{bgcol}{bgcol}{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.01\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{-8pt}
\begin{center}
\parbox[b]{0.75\linewidth}{
    \begin{center}
     \textcolor{white}{PET} \textcolor{white}{$\cdot$} \textcolor{white}{pet}
    \end{center}
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}

\include{Currículo 1}
\include{Currículo 2}
%============================================================================%
%
%
%
%   DOCUMENT END
%
%
%
%============================================================================%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: a minipage never breaks.

Comment: I used article as the document class.

Comment: you have not provided any code we can run to see the problem, but you have a parbox in a minipage in a fcolorbox. any one  of those is a box so will prevent page breaking.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know... There's any way I can substitute them?

Comment: you have not said what you want to do, just posted a small fragment of code no one can run, you just added a lot more code but still not in a form anyone can use,

Comment: Ok... So, what I'm trying to do is make the three parts (lines of research, areas of expertise and projects) behave like a text and fill the entire sheet before breaking the text and continuing on the next page. But as I try to do that, the "projects" part just won't be visible. The text is there and there's no error being accused, but part of the projects' text just won't appear, even though it's there and, by correspondence in the editor, it begins just below the blue line. I used a template to generate this and I was wondering if there's any way I can make it behave the way I envisaged.

Comment: In the code, the parts are named in portuguese, so "lines of research" is "linhas de pesquisa", "areas of expertise" is "áreas de atuação" and "projects" is "projetos".

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding what you're wanting to do because you have so much whitespace spreading your code out (the fact that I can't read Portuguese doesn't help either).  But when you have `\begin{minipage}[c][0.25\textheight][t]{\linewidth}`, the `0.25\textheight` is telling TeX that this box takes up a quarter of the height of the page (which should be `a4paper`, not `A4`, btw (and something is still strange with your text height).  Changing that to `0.5\textheight` after `% ÁREA DE ATUAÇÃO` makes them no longer overlap.  But that's more of a bandage and doesn't really fix the problem.  My bigger suggestion would be to step back and make sure you understand what the various parts of your code are doing, and why you have them the way that you have them.